# Adding Kernel module to ubuntu

Tags: c, module, linux-kernel

Makefile Code:

```
obj-m += hello.o

all:    
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules
clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

Errors Encountered:

```
make -C /lib/modules/4.4.0-31-generic/build M=/home/fast modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-31-generic'
make[2]: *** No rule to make target '/home/fast/hello.c', needed by 
'/home/fast/hello.o'.  Stop.
Makefile:1403: recipe for target '_module_/home/fast' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/fast] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-31-generic'
Makefile:4: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I'm not getting what kind of errors are these.
I can upload the kernel threading code if needed. Any type of help will be appreciated!

Comment: What is the relation to POSIX threads? They are not available at kernel level, last I checked.

Comment: does your C file exist at the specified location?

Comment: It doesn't have any relation. I've removed the tag, mistakenly did that.

Comment: Yes it exists there in the specified directory!

Comment: Just to be sure, what is the output of : `ls -l /home/fast/hello.c`  Note: This is not a good idea to have the source of your module at the root of your home directory. You should put the source in a sub folder.